# questions on methods of LinkedList Java

Tags: java, linked-list

Hi I'm very new to Java and have this problem with Linked List. My find and max methods are not producing the correct output. 
The find method is to take a type E element as argument, and returns true if the item is in the linked List, or false otherwise.
The max method is to return the maximum element in the list if the list is not empty, or null if empty list. The comparison has to be done by compareTo().

I have tried finding "Apple", which is indeed in the list, however, return false.
Also the max element I got back is "Apple", instead of "Watermelon".

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
  public E max(){
      Iterator<E> iterator=iterator();
      E max = iterator.next();
      while (iterator.hasNext())
      {  
         E next = iterator.next();
         if (max.compareTo(next) > 0) 
            max = next;
      }
    return max;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (current.equals(e)){
          return true;
```

You need to compare to the Node's item, not the Node itself.

```
if (max.compareTo(next) > 0) 
        max = next;
```

That comparison needs to be reversed: You have found a new `max` if the old one is *smaller* than the current item.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes by reversing the comparison, the output is Watermelon. However, I tried other random string in for testing, it failed. Also, how do I compare to the Node's item?